# Example of an elliptic curve with trivial torsion subgroup and rank 0

Tags: elliptic-curves

What is an example of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with trivial torsion subgroup and rank 0?

Comment: I needed one of those once: see p. 2 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/crelle.pdf.  (I chose the one that I did for rather sentimental reasons.  Really the way to do it is just to look in Cremona's tables as Alvaro suggests.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need a single example? In that case $y^2+2y=x^3+2x+1$ works

Comment: How one can see that this elliptic curve fulfills the conditions?

Answer (score 4):

As Alvaro notes, Cremona's tables are a definite source. Following the link on Cremona's web site to lmfdb.org, you can search more easily, and the exact search for curves with trivial torsion and rank 0 can be encoded in the following URL

http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q?conductor=&rank=0&torsion=1

Answer (score 3):

If you need a source of examples, you should look through the "[Elliptic Curve Data](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/ftp/data/)" by John Cremona (et al.).

For example, at [this link](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/ftp/data/allcurves.00000-09999.gz) you can find a list of curves of conductor between $0$ and $9999$, and the last two digits are the rank, and the order of the torsion subgroup. So you are looking for curves whose line in that table ends in "] 0 1". Searching with my browser I find $11065$ such curves:

- 11 a 2 [0,-1,1,-7820,-263580] 0 1
- 19 a 2 [0,1,1,-769,-8470] 0 1
- 26 a 2 [1,0,1,-460,-3830] 0 1
- 26 b 2 [1,-1,1,-213,-1257] 0 1
- ...

Etc.